# Compile-time and run-time costs of implicit float conversions

Tags: c, gcc, clang, implicit-conversion

Let's say I have the following C struct:

```
typedef struct {
    float a, b;
} Floats;
```

I then have a function that will create instances of this struct:

```
Floats createFloats(float aVal, float bVal) {
    Floats f = {aVal, bVal};
    return f;
}
```

There are now essentially 4 possible (syntactic) ways of creating the same struct:

```
Floats f1 = createFloats(0.0f, 1.0f);             // (A) [Canonical?]
Floats f2 = createFloats(0.0, 1.0);               // (B)
Floats f3 = createFloats(0, 1);                   // (C)
Floats f4 = createFloats(((float)0), ((float)1)); // (D)
```

My question is, what compile-time and runtime differences are there between the above 4 methods of creating my struct? Specifically, when do the implicit float conversions occur (say for clang and gcc). I have been advised against `(C)` (and `(D)` seems overkill), but if the conversion happens at compile time, surely there is no difference between any of the above methods?

Comment: There is no run-time conversion being made in case A to C, it's all done compile-time (like case D always will be). But if you really want to know, check the generated code, it's the only way to know.

Comment: Well, what does the assembly tell you?

Comment: The compiler won't implicitly calculate the return value of a function unless you specify [constexpr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check such things quite simple. Compile your example into an object file with debug information and run objdump to disassemble it and display the assembly along with the C source code:

```
cc -g -c example.c
objdump -dS example.o
```

Doing that will for your example show that even without optimizations each variant produces exactly the same assembler code.

Comment: Actually, there is a `-S` flag to stop compiler (at least gcc and clang) after assembly generation stage, writing assembly to output (text) file. There is also `-fverbose-asm` to introduce some comments in resulting assembly.

Comment: Unless you don't have a prototype, in which case you get undefined behavior, but probably different undefined behavior in case 3.